# Substitute all letters except the first one in all words

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var substitute_with = "_";
const regex = /\B\w/g;

var result = text.replaceAll(regex, substitute_with);
```

This code substitutes all letters with underscore, except the first one in all words.

This works fine for the English language, but I need the same with both English and Cyrillic.

Example:

> Это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне.

Online regex: https://regex101.com/r/scjHae/1

What can I try next?

Comment: Can you give an example of some Cyrillic text that fails?

Comment: Count the length, trap the first character then fill to length.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) (with `u` flag), and instead of `\B`, use a look behind assertion:

```js
const result = "They all shouted Слава Україні!".replaceAll(/(?<=\p{L})\p{L}/gu, "_");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just pay a attention it will throw you an error on Safari/iOS devices.

Comment: Apple provides support for this in [Safari 16.4 beta release](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16_4-release-notes). Safari for iOS has it in version 16.4. It's almost 5 years too late (since it was published in ECMA Script 2018), but better late than never?

Comment: Finally! Hope it also supports non-fixed width lookbehinds.